# c# playing movie in windows media player "Not" embedded

Tags: c#, wmp

I have looked around, everything I find is talking about embedding it.

I do not want to embed it. I want to click a button and launch windows media player seperatly.

For example, I have a location saved in XML file. I have a right click to click Play. It pulls the location. like so.

```
    int dd = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    string eLoc = dataGridView1.Rows[dd].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    if (eLoc == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have not saved a location for this movie","Movie Play",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(eLoc);
        ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("wmplayer.exe", eLoc.ToString());
        Process.Start(ps);
    }
```

As you can see, I have a pop up to view, what the string is.

It is this. I added %20 to replace spaces, thinking that was the problem but it isn't.
[image: Movie Locaiton]

As you can see it pulls the full location. All I get back from windows media player is this.

[image: WMP Error]

Any ideas? To me it seems like this should be working..

Comment: Can you play that avi file in Media Player? Maybe it's corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working now. It was the spaces causing the errors, I changed to this, and works perfect now.

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("wmplayer.exe", "\""+eLoc+"\"");
```

Comment: If this solution worked for you, you should mark it as the correct solution (check the green checkmark you see next to it).  This closes the question and helps guide others to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working, in fact on my computer and with a different path it does work, I suspect the file is damaged like jfs suggested.

Comment: I can play the movie fine by just double clicking on it. I just thought about something maybe because it is on a different partition? I will move the file to my C: and try it that way. I will post back.

Thank you guys for taking the time to post.